# My sql database backup in a .SQL file on client side?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, backup

i am creating a small tool using C# and MySQL, this tool has a small db in MySQL i want to backup the DB as a .SQL file that i can again load to MySQL when needed.

the problem is how to get .SQL file on client side using any query etc. and load it back to db.

i don't want to use sql dump or any other method for which i have to write a batch file or call an external process on client.

is there any simple and straight forward way to it with c# programming

help needed 
regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All object definitions you can get using SHOW CREATE TABLE, SHOW CREATE VIEW, SHOW CREATE TRIGGER, ... and so on; all objet names you can get from [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema.html) system database.

Only 'INSERT INTO table' statements you should generate itself.